# Django images not found in page view but was save after post request

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles, imagefield

I was trying to save an image but it can't be displayed through the browser. It was successfully saved in the exact location but when I pasted the link it says, "Page not found". Could someone help me with what's going on?

**See output:**
[Browser View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5xVV.png)

**Code:**
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBCCW.png)

Settings configuration:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

###### urls.py

###### This must be applied in your settings configuration.

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    ....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```